# Unity Attaching objects in game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Hello I am having a problem and I dont know how to solve it.
I want to create a 3d puzzle where the player needs to move multiple 3D objects to put them together. I already know how to implemet the movement (LeanTouch) but I need a way to recognize when two objects touch each other in special places. Then I would use transform to combine them. Does anyone have an Idea how to solve this?

Comment: Add them to a parent? So they move together

Comment: Give them `Rigidbody` and then use physics and [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html) and in specific [Fixed joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to create child objects with the colliders in the specific places you want to detect collision at. Then in OnCollisionEnter() you can practically combine them by creating a new parent of the two objects. Here's an example of an approach I took:

I set up my colliders like this: [image: Collider Setup]

Then on the individual colliders I added this code. Front is just the tag attached to the collider shown in the hierarchy.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Front"))
        {
            var newParent = new GameObject();
            newParent.transform.SetParent(collision.transform.parent.parent); // Get the parent of the current gameobject the collider is attached to
            collision.transform.parent.SetParent(newParent.transform); // Doing .parent because this is the child collider
            transform.parent.SetParent(newParent.transform);
        }
    }
```

It's not perfect, but the result is that the objects were combined under the same parent. [image]

Alternatively, you could simply make one cube the child of the other by removing NewParent and replacing it with collision.transform.parent.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use colliders for that, and then use the collision event